# Tracks are listed in the wrong order when iTunes is importing CDs

Tags: itunes, import

I am importing a CD to iTunes and find that when it appears the track listings are in the wrong order. The tracks themselves are labelled correctly as in track 1 and track 8 etc. but appear in the iTunes import page in a scrambled order. Can anyone help?

Comment: Presumably default sort is 'import date' which will reverse the sort. Click the header again & it should flip.

Comment: Many thanks. On importing the cd whilst showing incorrect out of order tracks on the iTunes import page, it imported the cd with the correct order of tracks.  All was well in the end. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Tracks are sorted by the selected sort column. To sort by track number, choose the track number column header and observe the sort arrow appear next to the header.

Comment: @guy Welcome to Ask Different! If an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted using the check mark button on the left. Thanks